# MILP solver for black box function

Tags: python, linear-programming

I need to solve a problem that has both integer and continuous values. However, I the function to be optimized is solved remotely.

I need a MILP solver that can optimize the parameters to F(x) without me modeling out all of F(x)

All of the Python MILP solvers I've seen AFAIK require you to model the problem, give the constraints, and then it solves it. I need one that can optimize the parameters just by sending parameters and getting results from the remote server.

I'd like to not have to build my own gradient descent solver.

Comment: MILP solvers only do fully specified **linear** models. A black-box function however is not linear (if it was you could quite easily recover the coefficients). localsolver.com has some new facilities to handle black-box functions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into LocalSolver. I need an optimizer that will optimizer a black-box problem. Maybe calling it an MILP is the issue, but I do need it to allow for discrete integer values.

Comment: I would call it an MINLP.